# javascript, how can this function possibly return an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, concatenation

```
function whatTheHeck(obj){
  var arr = []

  for(o in obj){
    arr.concat(["what"])
  }

  return arr
}

whatTheHeck({"one":1, "two": 2})
```

The concat function completely fails to do anything. But if I put a breakpoint on that line in Firebug and run the line as a watch it works fine. And the for loop iterates twice but in the end arr still equals [].

Comment: Actually even without the loop it still fails. The only thing that works is to say straight `return [].concat(["what"])`. Something is very wrong with the world.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`Array.concat` creates a new array - it does not modify the original so your current code is actually doing nothing.  It does not modify `arr`.

So, you need to change your function to this to see it actually work:

```
function whatTheHeck(obj){
  var arr = [];

  for(o in obj){
    arr = arr.concat(["what"]);
  }

  return arr;
}

whatTheHeck({"one":1, "two": 2});
```

If you're trying to just add a single item onto the end of the array, `.push()` is a much better way:

```
function whatTheHeck(obj){
  var arr = [];

  for(o in obj){
    arr.push("what");
  }

  return arr;
}

whatTheHeck({"one":1, "two": 2});
```

This is one of the things I find a bit confusing about the Javascript array methods.  Some modify the original array, some do not and there is no naming convention to know which do and which don't.  You just have to read and learn which work which way.

Comment: Woah, that was really stupid of me. Where was I when that was explained somewhere? Some things modify your objects and some make new ones and I just assumed...

Comment: Also note that a basic for-in loop on an object will loop through inherited properties in addition to the ones that were set manually.  So a for-in like this should check that `o` is one of the properties that was set "manually" on `obj` (i.e. use `if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(o)) continue;` before the push).