# Difference between array of objects in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I'm using Angular. I'm trying to compare two arrays of objects
I was able to get it working doing it like this:

```
  var compareUsers = function () {
    //Comparing assigned groups with all to return available users
    var assignedUsersIds = {};
    var usersIds = {};
    availableUsers = []; //declared higher up, populated with user objects on load

    //assignedUsers, declaired higher up, populated by function calling compareUsers
    assignedUsers.forEach(function (el, i) {
      assignedUsersIds[el.id] = assignedUsers[i];
    });

    allUsers.forEach(function (el, i) {
      usersIds[el.id] = allUsers[i];
    });

    for (var i in usersIds) {
        if (!assignedUsersIds.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            availableUsers.push(usersIds[i]);
        }
    };
    console.log(availableUsers);
    return availableUsers;
  }
```

I found a better way to do it so I refactored it to this, using `lodash`:

```
  var compareUsers = function () {
    availableUsers = _.filter(allUsers, function(user){
      return !_.findWhere(assignedUsers, user);
    });
    console.info(availableUsers);
    return availableUsers;
  }
```

However, I'm not getting the correct results and not sure what I messed up. The new methods returns `availableUsers` which are in the `assignedUsers` list for some groups. The first time it runs, it seems to work but if I keep changing what group i'm looking at the results are all off and don't add up.

I found this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147278/using-underscores-difference-method-on-objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you are using `Array.push`, which is always adding up (obviously), no matter how often you call `compareUsers`.

In the second example you are overwriting `availableUsers` each time you are calling `compareUsers` with the result of `_.filter`

I'd suggest that instead of doing:

```
availableUsers = _.filter(allUsers, function(user){
    return !_.findWhere(assignedUsers, user);
});
```

you do:

```
availableUsers = availableUsers.concat(_.filter(allUsers, function(user){
    return !_.findWhere(assignedUsers, user);
}));
```

This should work. It will concat the `availableUsers` array with the result of `_.filter`.

Comment: Hey so I just tried it. At first it said `couldn't concat undefined` which is  likely because I didn't declare it to be an array. So at the very top of the function I set `availableUsers = [];` then what you suggested but now it's just returning an empty array

Comment: This might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962953/javascript-how-can-this-function-possibly-return-an-empty-array

Comment: It will not work if you are setting it as an empty array at the top of the function. In the first example you comment "declared higher up". You should also declare the array outside the function in the second example. I think your lodash filter function is not doing what you want it to do.

Comment: It's running but I'm still getting the same issue as before. I'm going to sleep for now, I'll have to get back to this tomorrow. I'll update if i figure it out.

Comment: Okay, I know what the issue is. Angurlajs is adding a property to the objects called `haskey` but my assigned users array doesn't have this. So when it's checking if the objects are the same, it's seeing this property for one object and not the other so it's returning false. I can't compare the entire object, I have to stick with comparing IDs